# Kafka Consumer as a service which continuously polls messages from a Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to create an independent server which continuously polls data from a Kafka Topic. Till now I have created a vertx server and a Kafka Consumer. The issue is when we start the server it drains the queue and polls all the messages currently present but when new messages will arrive later it wont be able to consume them. I need to implement some logic in my server which able it to continuously poll the data and drain the queue.

Comment: Can you please explain why it's unable to consume? What you're describing is the default behavior of an infinite Kafka consumer loop, which doesn't require Vertx

Comment: @OneCricketeer after I consume these messages from Kafka..I need to send the messages to elastic search via rest API. So to achieve that I will require some kind of web service that's why I have used vertx. Is it possible to achieve this via vertx?

Comment: I'm sure it is, but have you considered using Kafka Connect Elasticsearch sink?

Comment: You should show your code as a [MCVE] and show you producing a message that never gets consumed